# difficulty inputing dataframes into metafor, do I need to remanipulate the data?

Tags: r, metafor

I have two dataframes with odds ratios (with 95% confidence intervals) of a couple superpowers.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Superpower = c("Flight", "Strength", "Money"), OddsRatio = c("1", "2", "3"), LowerCI = c("0.5","1.5","2.5"), UpperCI = c("1.5","2.5","3.5")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Superpower = c("Flight", "Strength", "Money"), OddsRatio = c("2", "2", "4"), LowerCI = c("1.5","2.5","3.5"), UpperCI = c("2.5","3.5","4.5")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to use metafor to create a fixed effects meta analysis outputting odds ratios for the superpowers but could not figure out how to input the dataframes into metafor. Would someone be able to aid me with this?

If it matters for data manipulation, the odds ratios/confidence intervals were extracted from a glm model via cbind(mdl$coefficients, confint(mdl)).

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use run `vignette("metafor")` and you will get a very clear explanation for all options, including fixed-effect.

Comment: And see here: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:assembling_data_or